# Fortran linking error : undefined reference to `***_mp_***_'

Tags: module, linker, makefile, fortran

I think my problem may be relevant for many people, because many scientific projects are using Fortran today and they mostly contain a lot of file, use Make and programs often are calling functions from other modules.

One program is calling public subroutine "readtsmfile" of a module "tsmio.mod".

This program (test_tsmparser.F90) use tsmio.F90 and tsmformat.F90. Corresponding CMakeList file :

```
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src)                                
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/test)
include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/utils/xml/sax)
add_executable(test_tsmparser test_tsmparser.F90)
```

Module tsmio.F90 itself also use tsmformat.F90. CMakeList for the folder of library modules :

```
include_directories(${SplineLib_BINARY_DIR}/utils/xml/strings)                                                                                                        
include_directories(${SplineLib_BINARY_DIR}/utils/xml/sax)
include_directories(${SplineLib_BINARY_DIR}/utils/xml/dom)
include_directories(${SplineLib_BINARY_DIR}/src)
include_directories(${SplineLib_BINARY_DIR}/utils/strings)
set(splinelib_src
   utils.F90 global.F90 basisFunctions.F90 bezierPatches.F90
   bezierConverter.F90 tSplineFormat.F90 pbsplines.F90 meshes.F90       nurbs.F90
   igaio.F90 tspsio.F90 xmlio.F90 igesio.F90
   tsmio.F90 TSMFormat.F90 tsmConverter.F90
   abstractSpline_geomOps.F90 abstractSpline.F90)

 add_library(splinelib ${splinelib_src})

install(TARGETS splinelib DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
install(FILES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/basfnc.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/errhndl.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/glblconst.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/mathfcn.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/pbsplines.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bezierpatches.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/bezierconverter.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/igaio.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tspsio.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/xmlio.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/igesio.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/nurbs.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/abstrspl_geomops.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/abstrsplmod.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tsplineformat.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tsmformat.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tsmio.mod
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/tsmconverter.mod
    DESTINATION ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)`
```

During making am getting an error :

```
Linking Fortran executable test_tsmparser   
 cd /home/tk207547/src/splinelib/build/test/cases/tsm && /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/test_tsmparser.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/opt/intel/Compiler/14.0/3.174/rwthlnk/bin/intel64/ifort      -warn -stand f08 -free -std08 CMakeFiles/test_tsmparser.dir/test_tsmparser.F90.o  -o test_tsmparser  -L/home/tk207547/src/splinelib/lib -i_dynamic 
CMakeFiles/test_tsmparser.dir/test_tsmparser.F90.o: In function `MAIN__':
/home/tk207547/src/splinelib/test/cases/tsm/test_tsmparser.F90:(.text+0x146): undefined reference to `tsmio_mp_readtsmfile_'
```

It seems that it cannot see this module or this function for some reasons, but I don't understand why.

Module file tsmio.mod is created, function is public...

Where should I search for a problem ?

Comment: The compilation command that causes this should be in your question.

Comment: My case is different, because I use Cmake and Make for building, linking and compiling the whole project.

Comment: It does not matter if you use CMake, Make, SCons, waf or whatever, the command to the linker or compiler caused by the build system is what matters. You should include all information you have. probably also the Makefiles.

Comment: This is not the command, cmake hides it by default, you must enable verbose output.

Comment: See http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_FAQ#Is_there_an_option_to_produce_more_.27verbose.27_compiling.3F

Comment: Time to show your cmake configuration and how you set the dependencies there. You do not seem to be linking in any other object files.

Comment: I added CMakeLists and dependecies. Thanks for helping. Tell me, if you need some more information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should tell CMake to link `test_tsmparser` against `splinelib`:

```
target_link_libraries(test_tsmparser splinelib)
```

Include all other libraries your code depends on in this statement.